# Check all the resources associated with my IAM role

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I've been trying to clean up on some of the IAM roles in my AWS account. I want to see what AWS resources are associated with my IAM role. I know that we can check last activity tab, but I don't see an option to confirm if this role is not attached to any AWS resource.

Comment: How do you define "the resources associated with my IAM role"? Associated how?

Comment: e.g 'my-iam-role' is assigned to which ec2 instance(s)

Comment: I don't think there is any way, except by iterating over your instances and checking their roles.

Comment: ok thanks for your help! yeah, I've been doing the same. But the challenge is "what if my iam role is used by some other services as well?"

Comment: Sadly same. I think there is no universal solution for that. Maybe there are some third-party tools for that?

Comment: I think no, but let me check.

Comment: Using AWS CLI, you can run the command [`aws ec2 describe-iam-instance-profile-associations`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-iam-instance-profile-associations.html) to list all EC2-IAM profile associations.